# MySQL Why automatically sum when using aggregate function

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to write a MySQL query that calculate Standard Deviation of a numeric column without using STD(). My working query is as below:

```
SELECT sqrt(power((amount-avg(amount)),2)/count(amount))
FROM Orders;
```

Please just treat 'amount' as the column name and 'Orders' as the table name. My question is why there is an automatically sum of all results of power((amount-avg(amount)),2) without using a sum function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using count() function, which is an aggregate function, thus you get all rows GROUPed. In your query, amount is not calculated as a sum, it uses just SOME row's value (it is not determined which row's values is used), since MySQL allows for using non-grouped columns combined with grouped ones.

Read more here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

If you wish to implement it only yourself, you can try query like this:

```
SELECT @avg:=(SELECT avg(amount) FROM Orders), @cnt:=(SELECT count(*) FROM Orders), 
       SQRT(SUM(POWER(amount-@avg,2)/@cnt)) as std
FROM Orders
```

This will do two fast queries getting average and count only once (since these are still the same for every row) and then it will sum up your formula and return sqrt of it as std.

Comment: Yeah. But it still only calculate everything for first record's amount, right? Although aggregate function make every record as a group, it still need sth like a for loop to sum calculation result for every record. I think imran's answer is correct.

Comment: No, the situation is not that each row is considered as a group separately. Instead, the contrary is true: all rows are considered as one big group and data is aggregated through this big group - count() will give you all rows count. The 'amount' will give you some random amount, it does NOT give you the first row's amount every time, it depends on your data.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense to me now. It seems that every time I run this query it will return result that calculate everything for the first row's amount. It probably be default of MySQL I guess. How to write query to calculate std without using STD() in this case? Thanks!

Comment: It makes no sense to answer your question here in a comment, once you already selected a 'winning' answer from someone who is not correct.

Comment: Well I can help you with SQL statements but I have no idea how Standard Deviation should be calculated. Is there any reason why you do not want to use STD() ?

Comment: I just want to try to implement STD function here.

Comment: OK if you tell me the formula then I can write you SQL query. Is it this? https://psyc261green.files.wordpress.com/2008/02/sdddddddddd.gif

Comment: I do not understand what is the x with the line above it. I assume 'x' here is your amount, but what is x with line above it? Should it be the average of amount?

Comment: Yeah. x is particular amount, x with a bar is avg(amount) and n is count(amount).

Comment: Then I think you cannot use MySQL aggregate functions for this. You can look at the aggregation function as like on a foreach cycle which goes through all rows. You can't calculate aggregate of another aggregate (sum out of avg would need to go through the data more than once). Even if you manage to write it in a single query, it will be very slow, because it will have to calculate the AVG(amount) repeatedly for every row. If you need purely sql solution, you'll have to use variables to remember the avg().

Comment: I'll look at implementation of for loop in sql. Thanks.

Comment: @shengjie-zhang: I'm not sure why you insist on SQL implementation. You can try using sql variables, this will work. See edited answer for example. Let me know please if this suits your needs.

Answer (score -1):

Your `amount` column do not calculate sum. Its the SOME row's value of your table.

Comment: Thanks! So this query is not calculating std of variable amount? It just calculate the formula for first record's amount. Is that right?

Comment: No it is NOT the first row value! Well it can be, but doesn't have to be.

Comment: In MySQL, there is no first row or second row. Rows in general are treated as rows and nobody can tell which one goes first. The physical order of the table can be way different from the order you inserted your rows. You can even reorder the physical order of the rows some time later by ALTER TABLE  tbl ORDER BY  col.

Comment: It won't be a random row. It will be SOME row's value, but it won't be random. It will depend on how SQL gets the data, what is the physical structure of your table, etc. It is not specified which value is it going to be.